# Why did this flight never depart ? West Jet 1:00 pm on 2/01/19 from Toronto to Montreal

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, yyz, westjet

Why has West Jet flight bound for Montreal from Toronto on February 1 2019 at 1:00 pm never departed.

Comment: If it didn't depart, it must have been canceled. That happens, for a variety of reasons that airlines typically don't bother to make public on a flight-by-flight basis.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Answer (score 5):

This flight was cancelled.

Over the past few days, thousands and thousands of flights have been canceled across North American, especially in the area around Toronto, due to storms and temperatures reaching well below freezing.

These conditions have affected everything from the ability to  takeoff and land, as well as to prepare the aircraft.  For example, in Chicago they were unable to fuel planes due to the fuel pipes freezing shut!

This same flight was also canceled the day before as well, as were hundreds of other flights into and out of Toronto over the past few days.

Comment: Not sure if "uncontrollable" is an aviation term for very bad weather but the reason for the cancellation is indeed given as `1FX CXL WX UNCONTROLLABLE IN YYZ  *1815*HDQOCA` on the GDS

Comment: "CXL WX" means that the flight was canceled (CXL) due to weather (WX).